# Formatting money in twig templates

Tags: numbers, format, currency, twig

Are there any filters or something like that in twig template engine to format money or numbers?

Comment: Since the release of Twig Extensions 1.2.0 in October 2014, a [`localizedcurrency` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/intl.html#localizedcurrency) is available to format money in Twig, based on the locale. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28410078/1001110) for more information.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The `number_format` filter has been included in the Twig core since the end of December 2011. The relevant commit is [here](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/commit/0edcfdd).

Usage: `number_format(decimals, decimalSeparator, thousandSeparator)`

```
{{ total|number_format(2) }}
{{ total|number_format(0, '.') }}
{{ total|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
```

Read more about it in the [docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html)

Comment: Is there no way to do this user locale sensitive?

Comment: And this is the link to the doc http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html

Comment: Amazingly, none of the documentation and none of the SO answers hint that you have to parenthesise the first argument if it’s a formula. I had `{{ 100*done/total | number_format(2) }}` and it took me a good 30 minutes to figure out why the result was wrong. You have to write `{{ (100*done/total) | number_format(2) }}`.

Comment: @Timwi that's kind of expected since you're piping the `total` to the twig filter

Comment: @VitaliyZurian: It’s only expected if you know the operator precedence.

Comment: @Timwi thanks a lot, I was running into the same problem

Answer (score 39):

The [Twig Extensions library](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) contains a number of useful extensions for Twig. With the release of version 1.2.0, a [`localizedcurrency` filter](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html#localizedcurrency) has been added to the Intl extension. As the name suggests, this filter will format a number based on the current locale. It uses PHP's [`NumberFormatter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class to do so.

### Usage

This filter is very easy to use. The only required argument for the filter is the 3-letter [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency code. For instance, to display an amount of 27.99 in Euros, use the following line of code:

```
{{ price|localizedcurrency('EUR') }}
```

This will display different results depending on the locale:

- `€27.99` if the locale is set to `en`
- `27,99 €` if the locale is set to `fr`
- `€ 27,99` if the locale is set to `nl`

### Installation / setting the locale

Installation instructions for the Intl extension can be found in [this seperate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28410279/1001110).

Comment: How should one disable the `Thousand Separator` in `localizednumber` ??

Comment: @Trix interesting question. This is possible with PHP's `NumberFormatter`, but you will have to write a custom Twig Extension because the `localizedcurrency` filter does not support it. I think this deserves its own Stack Overflow question though. If you post the question and send me the link, I will post my answer there.

Comment: More gooder than number_format method I think, but both work just fine

Comment: I'm delighted with this localizedcurrency, localizeddate and localizednumber filters. However, in the case of the localizednumber I really would love to define a fixed amount of decimals. At the moment, I see the numbers using a number of decimals that is best approached by the filter, but it doesn't show a uniform output. In the same column there can be 0, 1, 2, 3 decimals... In the documentation I cannot manage to set a way for handling this. Any idea??? @NicWortel

Comment: Found it! localizednumber is great, but format_number (do not confuse with number_format) is awesome. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662974/how-to-increase-decimal-precision-on-percentage-format-using-twigs-intl-extensi

Answer (score 11):

If you are using an older version of twig and you don't want to install any extensions you can use the format filter like this:

```
{{ "%.2f"|format(total) }}
```

Not very nice, but it works.

Basically `format` works like [PHP's `sprintf` function](http://php.net/sprintf#example-4997)

Comment: I've used this and can confirm that it works.  Can you explain how it works?

Comment: No need, I've worked it out.  `format` works like PHP's `sprintf` function and that [can do currency formatting](http://php.net/sprintf#example-4997).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `format_currency`

From version 2.12 `format_currency` filter was added. More information in the official documentation https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format_currency.html

Comment: The `format_currency` filter is quite bad tho, as it is common to store money as integers, and the filter show the whole integer ...