# How to install the Intl extension for Twig

Tags: php, twig, intl, twig-extension

The [Intl extension](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html) is an extension for Twig that adds the `localizeddate`, `localizednumber` and `localizedcurrency` filters. How can I install and set up the extension so that I can use those filters in my Twig templates?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## Install the PHP intl extension

First of all, you will need the [PHP intl extension](https://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php), as the Twig extension is built on top of that. The Twig Intl extension will throw an Exception if the PHP intl extension is not enabled. [Installation instructions](https://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php) can be found in the official PHP documentation.

On Ubuntu/Debian machines, this is as easy as running the following command:

```
sudo apt install php-intl
```

On Windows machines, you probably have to uncomment the following line in php.ini:

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

For CentOS, or other architectures, follow the instructions [here](https://asdqwe.net/blog/enabling-installing-intl-package-php-from-terminal/). Note that CentOS requires both PECL and the GCC C++ compiler to be installed: `yum install php-pear` and `yum install gcc-c++`.

Once the extension is added to php.ini, then restart the web server.

## Install the Twig Extensions

Next, you will need the [Twig Extensions](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package (that contains the Intl extension, among others), which can be installed using Composer. Run this command in the command line:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

This will add the dependency to your `composer.json` and download it.

Note: the `localizednumber` and `localizedcurrency` filters were introduced in version 1.2.0, so you need at least that version if you want to use them.

## Adding the extension to Twig

If you are using Twig directly (i.e. not in a Symfony project), add the extension to the Twig environment manually:

```
<?php

use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension;

$twig = new Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new IntlExtension());
```

### Adding the extension to Twig (in Symfony)

If you are using a Symfony application, you can add the extension to Twig by creating a service and tagging it as a Twig extension in `config/services.yml`:

```
services:
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

## Setting the default locale

```
<?php

Locale::setDefault('nl-NL');
```

### Setting the default locale in Symfony

In `config/framework.yaml`, uncomment the `default_locale` setting:

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
```

Comment: For Symfony, config changes should be made in: app/config/services.yml

Comment: I had to use `Twig\Extra\Intl\IntlExtension` instead, but otherwise, the modification to `config/services.yaml` worked liek a charm!

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 3/4/5, with the autoconfiguration feature enabled, it's as easy as registering the extension as a service:

```
// config/services.yaml

services:
    …

    Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: ~
```

Comment: Update 2020: It seems the FQCN has changes, I had to use
`Twig\Extra\Intl\IntlExtension: ~`