# Twig: Unknown "localizednumber" filter

Tags: twig, symfony

When applying the Twig filter "localizednumber", the following error is thrown:

```
Unknown "localizednumber" filter in MyBundle:Home:home.html.twig at line 558.
```

I have installed Twig Extensions as well as PHP Intl.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the Intl extension for Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948853/how-to-install-the-intl-extension-for-twig)

Comment: @A.L adding twig intl to the services.yml did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you declare the Intl Extension in your services?

If not, add this:

```
<service id="twig.extension.intl"
         class="Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl">
    <tag name="twig.extension" />
</service>
```

in your `app/config/services.xml`.

Comment: for some reason I overlooked this. wasn't directly clear from the documentation. thanks!