# How to display date in a specific language using Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I installed the twig/extensions by typing:

```
composer require twig/extensions
```

I then added it as a service in the *services.yaml* file as follows:

```
twig.extension.intl:
  class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
  tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

My Twig code is:

```
{{ request.createdAt |  localizeddate('full', 'none', 'fr' ) }}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Attempted to load class "IntlTimeZone" from the global namespace. Did
>   you forget a "use" statement?

Any hints ?

Comment: do you have PHP intl ext installed? php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php

Comment: Have a look at [How to install the Intl extension for Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948853/how-to-install-the-intl-extension-for-twig). Your question seems to be a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @kallosz It worked!!! Great comment from a good guy , thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Nima I already installed it ! Anyway , thank you for the comment!

Comment: @kallosz Sorry it didn't appear in my search results

Comment: I linked to that question because the accepted answer explicitly mentions you have to install intl extension for php (as kallosz suggested here). Also, [The Intl Extension](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html) mentions that. You probably missed it.