# Symfony doesn't detect intl extension (running on XAMPP)

Tags: symfony, xampp, intl

Symfony Profiler tell me this deprectation message : Please install the "intl" PHP extension for best performance.

I enabled intl extension in my php.ini file and it appears in phpinfo, but the deprectation message still appears in Symfony.

I'm using XAMPP server on Windows 10.

Any idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the Intl extension for Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948853/how-to-install-the-intl-extension-for-twig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand precisely why but this fixed my problem : i updated the Symfony Intl package (from 5.0.4 to 5.0.7) inside my project and the message disappeared.